# Safari - How do I stop Facebook showing the 'Leaving Facebook' message every time I click an external link?

Tags: safari, facebook

I recently switched back to using Safari after using Chrome as my main browser on Mac for a few weeks. Safari was slow to adopt the new Facebook layout, but it finally has.
However, every time I click on an external link on Facebook, I get a message like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx3wY.png):

> **Leaving Facebook**
>
> We're just checking that you want to follow a link to this website:
>
> **https://www.your_url.com**

I find this *incredibly* annoying. I've had a browse around the Facebook settings and haven't seen anything obvious to turn it off.
How can I tell Facebook that I'm happy to follow any external links?

Comment: https://www.fiverr.com/rana_nadeem3041/solve-leaving-facebook-warning 
maybe help you but you will have to pay

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all extensions (and reload facebook) and see if the problem persists. If it disappears you can re-enable your extensions one by one (or more efficiently if there are many) and see which one is the culprit. In my case it was "AdGuard Advanced Blocking 1.7.4" (even though the AdGuard was disabled).